# Graphics.DrawString() & leading padding spaces for Proportional Font

Tags: c#, drawstring

I've been using a monospaced font to render a table onto a graphics object, and to align the columns of text I'd been padding the text using space characters.

I've been asked to change the font to a proportional font, and no surprise, but the columns don't line up anymore.

If given a string such as

```
"Bill-of-Material Edits\r\n------------------------------\r\n200   510024   Door 24\" x 58\"\r\n  3   530058   Panel 58\" x 58\"\r\n";
```

how do I ensure that the 3 lines up properly under the one's place on the 200 value from the line above, and subsequently have the 510024 sit directly above the 530058?

Here's the code I use to draw the string:

```
 var fnt = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
        StringFormat strFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic);
        strFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;

        string text = "Bill-of-Material Edits\r\n------------------------------\r\n200   510024   Door 24\" x 58\"\r\n  3   530058   Panel 58\" x 58\"\r\n";
        g.DrawString(text, fnt, Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(10f, 10f, 38.1062851f, 12.9231777f), strFormat);
```

I tried replacing the spaces with other characters such as unicode control characters (0x0080) to no avail. I've also tried using string.Format() with formatters like {0,10} which didn't help either.

What do I do to get my columns to line up?

Answer (score 3):

You can't make it work like this.  Draw each individual string in its column, pass the Rectangle of the column.  How wide you make each column is up to you.